# How do i split an Integer array?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an array as follows: 
c(26.5, 27, 27.5, 28, 28.5, 29, 29.5)  and c(80,222,303,408,276,151)

i want to split each array as,

```
array[0] -> [26.5] 
array[1] -> [27]
array[2] -> [27.5]
```

and so on...

finally i want to combine both the array (in PHP) as,

```
array[0] -> [26.5,80]
array[1] -> [27,222]
array[2] -> [27.5,303]
array[3] -> [28,408]
array[4] -> [28.5,276]
array[5] -> [29,151]
```

help me find a solution..

Comment: confusing.....Un clear

Comment: I guess you are constructing a complex number from two arrays. And your desired results are likely to be a two-dimensional array.

Comment: these are floats, not integers

Comment: how can it be tagged with php and javascript? Which are you actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a1 = array(26.5, 27,  27.5, 28,  28.5, 29, 29.5);
$a2 = array(80,   222, 303,  408, 276,  151     );

array_map(null, $a1, $a2);
```

does elegantly something very similar to what you want (it will also give you an extra `[29.5, null]` element).

Comment: Thanks. it works with array that i manually enter. but it is not working when i fetch it from database. This is how it is stored. Array ( [0] => 80, 222, 303, 408, 276, 151 ). can i get a way to separate this and map?

Comment: The big question is, why the heck is it stored like that?

Comment: it is the data given to me like that.. 1000s of data are generated using "r" and the output is stored this way.

Answer (score -1):

I will try to illustrate things here to make it clear for you.
If you already have an array, then it is indexed.You don't need to 'split' any thing.

```
$array1 = array(1,2);
echo $array1[0];  // 1
echo $array1[1];  // 2
```

For the second part you are talking about creating a new 2 dimensional array which means it is an array of other arrays. I think the best way is mentioned by Amadan :

```
 array_map(null, $a1, $a2);
```

Hope this helps